# Negation of the statement in predicate logic

Tags: logic

I have problem with negating this sentence. I had it on my last exam and lost 5 points. The problem is next:
__If there is a new planet, then it is smaller than all known planets. __
Actually, bigger problem is to translate it to predicate logic. Thank you.

Comment: the negation of $p \to q$ is $ p \ \land \neg q$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE, please try editing your post and including your attempt at solving this problem.